# strategy for hit detection over a net connection, like Quake or other FPS games

Tags: networking, tcp, udp

I'm learning about the various networking technologies, specifically the protocols UDP and TCP.

I've read numerous times that games like Quake use UDP because, "it doesn't matter if you miss a position update packet for a missile or the like, because the next packet will put the missile where it needs to be."

This thought process is all well-and-good during the flight path of an object, but it's not good for when the missile reaches it's target.  If one computer receives the message that the missile reached it's intended target, but that packet got dropped on a different computer, that would cause some trouble.

Clearly that type of thing doesn't really happen in games like Quake, so what strategy are they using to make sure that everyone is in sync with instantaneous type events, such as a collision?

Comment: Wow, that is a small question with a big BIG answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've identified two distinct kinds of information:

- updates that can be safely missed, because the information they carry will be provided in the next update;
- updates that *can't* be missed, because the information they carry is not part of the next regular update.

You're right - and what the games typically do is to separate out those two kinds of messages within their protocol, and require acknowledgements and retransmissions for the second type, but not for the first type.  (If the underlying IP protocol is UDP, then these acknowledgements / retransmissions need to be provided at a higher layer).

Comment: I agree completely.  So what is the strategy for dealing with those "can't miss" updates?  Some sort of TCP?  Or roll-you-own UDP that requires ACK?  Neither one of those seems right to me.

Comment: It's possible to have a parallel TCP connection, but mostly it's just a custom packet-numbering-and-acknowledgement protocol built on top of UDP.  These packets can go over the same port as the unacknowledged packets - you can just have a identifier at the start of the packet that says what type it is (and you might even have more types, like packets-that-must-be-processed-in-order).

Comment: My preferred approach is a TCP connection to a designated "control" server, and then using an ad-hoc udp topology for non-essential updates, like character movement.

Answer (score 1):

When you say that "clearly doesn't happen", you clearly haven't played games on a lossy connection.  A popular trick amongst the console crowd is to put a switch on the receive line of your ethernet connection so you can make your console temporarily stop receiving packets, so everybody is nice and still for you to shoot them all.

The reason that could happen is the console that did the shooting decides if it was a hit or not, and relays that information to the opponent.  That ensures out of sync or laggy hit data can be deterministically decided. Even if the remote end didn't think that the shot was a hit, it should be close enough that it doesn't seem horribly bad. It works in a reasonable manner, except for what I've mentioned above. Of course, if you assume your players are not cheating, this approach works quite reasonably.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but there seems to be two approaches you can take. Let the client decide if it's a hit or not (allows for cheating), or let the server decide.

With the former, if you shoot a bullet, and it looks like a hit, it will count as a hit. There may be a bit of a delay before everyone else receives this data though (i.e., you may hit someone, but they'll still be able to play for half a second, and then drop dead).

With the latter, as long as the server receives the information that you shot a bullet, it can use whatever positions *it* currently has to determine if there was a hit or not, then send that data back for you. This means neither you nor the victim will be aware of you hit or not until that data is sent back to you.

I guess to "smooth" it out you let the client decide for itself, and then if the server pipes in and says "no, that didn't happen" it corrects. Which I suppose could mean players popping back to life, but I reckon it would make more sense just to set their life to 0 and until you get a definitive answer so you don't have weird graphical things going on.

As for ensuring the server/client has received the event... I guess there are two more approaches. Either get the server/client to respond "Yeah, I received the event" or forget about events altogether and just think about everything in terms of state. There is no "hit" event, there's just HP before and after. Sooner or later, it'll receive the most up-to-date state.